# Pull request from local Git to GitHub

Tags: git, github

Can I pull request right to GitHub repo using "git request-pull " command? If yes, where I should take this link.

I tried to use this command with repo link and clone link, but it gives this expected error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Comment: Were you in the repository directory when you ran that command?

Comment: `git request-pull` is not meant to submit to github.  it's meant for a forked repo scenario.  check out the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull   but from the message you are getting you are clearly not running it from the correct directory.  Are you trying to run it from inside .git? or outside of your repo?

Comment: Also, have you pushed any commits?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by “pull request”.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22request-pull%22

Answer (score 1):

Even if you run this from the correct space locally it's not going to open a PR for you on `github` it's going to generate text that you can put into an email message and send to folks with a summary of your changes.

the syntax to run it is:

`git request-pull master <YOUR_GITHUBURL> <YOUR_BRANCHNAME>`
doc here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull

I would probably pipe that output into mail myself if I was going to use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `git request-pull` (which, as others have mentioned, is more for the "kernel style" of Git repo), you can use the GitHub CLI (https://cli.github.com) to create a PR from the command line:

1. Install the tool
2. `cd` to the repo in question
3. Do your work
4. `git add` the files you changed
5. `git commit`
6. `git push`
7. `gh pr create` and follow the prompts

Alternately, GitHub and other hosts will give a link after a successful push, which you can use to create a PR from a browser.